# UnitTest проерить текст на валидацию

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты

У меня есть некий коммент, нужно написать unittest на проверку что он не может быть пустым и не может быть меньше 10 символов.
В контроллере проверка есть

```
$request->validate([
            'comment' => 'required|string|min:10',
        ]);
```

Как сделать unittest на то что проверка не пускает пустой коммент?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 0):

Вариант которым я пользуюсь это метод `assertSessionHasErrors();` который проверяет наличие ошибок у определенного поля, тогда передаем в качестве параметра массив, где ключ - это имя поля, а значение - текст ошибки.
**Пример:**

```
$this->assertSessionHasErrors([
    'field' => 'Text error',
]);
```